# Get album with covers when syncronizing with iPod

Tags: ipod

I have 120GB iPod classic. Firmware 2.01.

It will connect without any problems with Ubuntu, sync albums both via Clementine and Rhythmbox, but covers will not sync?

Gtkpod kind of freezes the PC, so it was not useful for me.

Only Amarok will sync songs with their covers, but is very slow in recognizing the iPod. It installs too much KDE dependencies, which often render the system unusable.

Any ideas if this can be fixed (sync albums with artwork)?

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,